# Flutter TextInput.finishAutofillContext() doesn't work in iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, autofill

I want to use autofill feature for login page on my flutter app. I use AutofillGroup on the Form, autofillHints on each TextFormField, and TextInput.finishAutofillContext() on the login function.

It works perfectly on Android, i am able to save credentials and use it as autofill later. But somehow the save username/password prompt doesn't show up on iOS when i call the finishAutofillContext.

Is this a known bug for autofill in flutter?

Comment: Same issue here. I also tried the web, Chrome and Safari do not fill the username/password. Firefox seems to work. A minimal example: https://gist.github.com/maprohu/53fb19d7b1026e32948f496c4303bfac

Comment: @Marton i actually found the fix! Turns out my autofill in my iOS device was turned off I figured it out cause the message popped up when i run the app on iOS simulator so then i know the problem lays on my physical device and not flutter hehe

Comment: @ajubo Autofill is enabled on my iOS device, but credentials are not saved in keychain, however it works fine on my Android device. Do you have a solution for how it works?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to save email and password in the iCloud Keychain in Flutter for iOS and also using auto fill?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76621264/how-to-save-email-and-password-in-the-icloud-keychain-in-flutter-for-ios-and-als)